# Isn't this string compared with the content of the list from pytz.country_timezones

Tags: python, pytz

Not able to get the output for the following:

```
import pytz  # Python timezone library
for x in sorted(pytz.country_timezones):
    if "Asia" in pytz.country_timezones[x]:
        print(pytz.country_timezones[x])
```

following code provides me the output:

```
for x in sorted(pytz.country_timezones):
for y in pytz.country_timezones[x]:
    if "Asia" in y:
        print(pytz.country_timezones[x])
```

Why does't it compare and matches in the full list pytz.country_timezones[x] instead it's able to compare and match individual items in the list. Sorry new to python.

Answer (score 1):

`pytz.country_timezones[x]` is a list that contain multiple elements for example for `x="NZ"`, `pytz.country_timezones['NZ'] =['Pacific/Auckland', 'Pacific/Chatham']`.

In the first snippet, you ask if the exact expression `Asia` appears in `pytz.country_timezones[x]` while in the second snippet you as if `Asia` is part of one of the elements in `pytz.country_timezones[x]`.

Since `Asia` itself never appears in `pytz.country_timezones[x]` the first snippet will not print anything.

Comment: I understood with experimenting that the string needs to be the exact match to any of the member of the list associated with the key not a portion of the string in order to find it in the entries in the list if we look a list as a whole to search but if we try to match with the individual elements of that list associated with the key, we can pass any part of the string, it will find the matching entry for you from the list, but I'm still not very convinced by this. Why should not the part of the string also be able to be matched rather than exact entry? Little confused.

Comment: This is how it works. If you ask if a string `x` is in `y` where `y` is a list it checks if there exists an element in `y` which is exactly `x`. Note that it does not ask if `x==y`. It is consistent with is `x` in `y` where `y` is a string since it asks whether `x` is part of `y`.